# how to use presentedViewController when testing for modal launch

Tags: objective-c, ios, ocunit

I'm unit testing one of my view controllers and wanted to confirm that when a logic branch is hit, the modal view controller that I pop up with present:

---

### `viewDidLoad`

```
MWLoginViewController *loginController = [[MWLoginViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:loginController animated:YES];
```

The code is hit in the debugger when I put a breakpoint.

Now how do I test to see if this was launched?

---

### I am trying:

```
BOOL wasLoginViewController = [[mainVcSUT presentedViewController] isMemberOfClass:          [MWLoginViewController class]];

[Assert isTrue:wasLoginViewController];

NSLog(@"presented VC was: %@", [[mainVcSUT presentedViewController] class]);
```

The `NSLog` is telling me view controller was `null`.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue - did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 0):

> MWLoginViewController *loginController = [[MWLoginViewController alloc] init];

you are creating just an object , does it have it`s own view ? create viewcontroller either initwithnibname or init from storyboard , then check it

plus , you should not load another view from viewDidLoad: method ...

Comment: Hiding initWithNibName from within an init is perfectly fine.

Comment: dont load it in viewDidLoad , try this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2173865/1824510